# How to identify database users and their owned schemas before dropping server logins?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, logins

While deleting logins, there might be a possibility that there are users in databases along with chances that they own schemas in those databases.

Is there a way to find this out with a single `select`?

This is the warning message I get:

> Deleting server logins does not delete the database users associated
>   with the logins.  To complete the process, delete the users in each
>   database.  It may be necessary to first transfer the ownership of
>   schemas to new users.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use below query to look for the logins mapped as user to specific databases.
Hope it helps.

```
CREATE TABLE #tempww (
    LoginName nvarchar(max),
    DBname nvarchar(max),
    Username nvarchar(max), 
    AliasName nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO #tempww 
EXEC master..sp_msloginmappings 

-- display results
SELECT * 
FROM   #tempww 
ORDER BY dbname, username

-- cleanup
DROP TABLE #tempww
```

Answer (score 2):

The query below will return the schema owner information.  You can change the `JOIN` to sys.database_principals to a `LEFT JOIN` to also return schema owners that are not logins, such as database roles and users without a login.

```
SELECT
      sp.name AS OwningLogin
    , dp.name AS OwningUser
    , s.name AS SchemaName
FROM sys.schemas AS s
JOIN sys.database_principals AS dp ON
    dp.principal_id = s.principal_id
JOIN sys.server_principals AS sp ON
    sp.sid = dp.sid;
```